# Find summation of following series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

What will be the formula for following **infinite series**?

$$1 + \frac{1!}{x+1} + \frac{2!}{(x+1)(x+2)}+ \cdots$$

$$ x\ge2 $$

up to infinite

What pattern i got :

coefficient of  $ \frac{1!}{x+1}$  $(1+2+3+4+5+6+\cdots)$

coefficient of  $ \frac{2!}{(x+1)(x+2)}$ is $ -(2+6+12+20+\cdots)$

coefficient of  $ \frac{3!}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)} $ is $(3+12+30+\cdots)$

I want a formula as I put value of $n$ and get the answer.

Comment: do you mean 'closed form' or 'write it in one expression'?

Comment: just like summation of all natural numbers is (n)(n+1)/2 , i require the equivalent formula for above expression

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where did you get this from? Contextinate your question please :)

Comment: This is called 'closed-form expression', i.e. a function only of $n$. To get help I suggest you show some of your work first.

Comment: @Alizter: I am preparing for engineering entrance exam , this question was in my assignment , i tried using partial fraction , but not confident in it , so came here for help

Comment: @Alex ,@Alitzer I have made some edits please see

Comment: It sums to $\frac x{x-1}$, I believe.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I also get $x/(x-1)$.

Comment: sorry for really late reply , but yes correct answer was x/(x-1)
thanks @columbus8myhw

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x+1=\frac{\Gamma{(x+2)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}}$ and in general $(x+1)...(x+k)=\frac{\Gamma{(x+k+1)}}{\Gamma{(x+1)}}$ so your sum can be rewritten as
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{\Gamma{(k+1)}\Gamma{(x+1)}}{\Gamma{(x+k+1)}}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{\Gamma{(k+1)}\Gamma{(x+1)}}{\Gamma{(x+k+2)}}(x+k+1)$$
By the definition of the Beta function $$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma{(x)}\Gamma{(y)}}{\Gamma{(x+y)}}$$
we could rewrite the last summation in terms of the Beta function as 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(x+k+1)\cdot B(k+1,x+1)$$
But $$B(x,y)=\int^{1}_{0}u^{x-1}(1-u)^{y-1}\,du$$
Therefore 
\begin{align}&\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(x+k+1)\cdot B(k+1,x+1)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(x+k+1)\cdot \int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du\\&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}((x+1)\int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du+k\int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du)\\
&=(x+1)\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du+\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}k\int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du\\
&=(x+1)\int^{1}_{0}(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}u^{k})(1-u)^{x}\,du+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k\int^{1}_{0}u^{k}(1-u)^{x}\,du\\
&=(x+1)\int^{1}_{0}(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}u^{k})(1-u)^{x}\,du+\int^{1}_{0}u(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}ku^{k-1})(1-u)^{x}\,du\\
&=(x+1)\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{1-u}(1-u)^{x}\,du+\int^{1}_{0}u \frac{1}{(1-u)^2}(1-u)^{x}\,du\\
&=(x+1)\int^{1}_{0}(1-u)^{x-1}\,dx+\int^{1}_{0}u(1-u)^{x-2}\,du\\
&=(x+1)\cdot \frac{1}{x}+B(2,x-1)\end{align}
The last result is valid for any $x>1$.

Comment: thanks for the effort , but i my requirement is different

Comment: Don't you mean$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{\Gamma{(k+1)}\Gamma{(x+1)}}{\Gamma{(x+k+1)}}$$(Because $\Gamma(k+1)=k!$) (That sums to $\dfrac x{x-1}$, I believe.)

Comment: I see you've edited. But this isn't equal to $B(k+1,x+1)$, I'm afraid. That would be $\frac{\Gamma{(k+1)}\Gamma{(x+1)}}{\Gamma{(x+k+2)}}$. I might have done the math wrong, but I think you need $x\,B(k+1,x)$?

Comment: @ columbus8myhw: What about now? I think I remedied the mistake.

Comment: @columbus8myhw x/(x-1) is the correct answer

Comment: @null Wow, this thread was a while ago. And, that's what I wrote in my comment above: $\dfrac x{x-1}$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw , yeah my bad.... sorry for the late reply...ohh very late reply, btw if you are willing to post it as answer , i would like to accept it which is not possible in comments.